# JUnit test controller error

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, controller

this is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.COMPANY, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity find(@ModelAttribute CompanyDto request, @Valid @ModelAttribute PageableRequestModel pageRequest) {
    final Page<CompanyDto> dtoPg = companyService.find(request, pageRequest.getPageable());
    return new ResponseEntity(PagedResponseDto.of(dtoPg), HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

this is my controller test :

```
  @Test
   public void testListAll() throws Exception {     
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(COMPANY))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());  
   }
```

why error 'nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: page required !' ?? help me

Comment: How do you have set up your test? What is it's configuration? Could you also please post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Running controller.CompanyControllerTest
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,117  INFO: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/company],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.ResponseDto> com.kartuku.voucherweb.controller.CompanyController.put(java.util.List<com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.CompanyDto>) At line: 532.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,117  INFO: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/company],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.kartuku.voucherweb.controller.CompanyController.find(com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.CompanyDto,com.kartuku.voucherweb.util.PageableRequestModel) At line: 532.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,117  INFO: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/company],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.kartuku.voucherweb.controller.CompanyController.delete(java.util.List<com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.CompanyDto>) At line: 532.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,129  INFO: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@15b5480 At line: 532.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,157  INFO: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet '' At line: 430.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,157  INFO: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization started At line: 488.
06 Jan 2017 10:02:36,157  INFO: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 0 ms At line: 507.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.16 sec <<< FAILURE! - in controller.CompanyControllerTest
testListAll(controller.CompanyControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.16 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: page required !
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.PagedResponseDto.of(PagedResponseDto.java:29)
    at com.kartuku.voucherweb.controller.CompanyController.find(CompanyController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at controller.CompanyControllerTest.testListAll(CompanyControllerTest.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Paging value that you are passing to the PagedResponseDto.of(...) method is not valid.

This comes from the last line of your code in the stack trace before the NestedServletException was thrown:

```
at com.kartuku.voucherweb.dto.PagedResponseDto.of(PagedResponseDto.java:29)
```

Debug your test and check the values in your code.

You will either need to appropriately mock CompanyService and the call to CompanyService.find(...) (using something like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org)) or somehow provide an actual instance of CompanyService.